# How to access rest call in angular if having CORS issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Iam getting CORS issue with GET call.

```
XmlHttpRequest error: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin
```

I even tried jsonp approach,here I can seeing 200 response coming from that call in network tab.But Iam not able capture that data and display on UI and Iam getting following error on console

```
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

Below is my code

```
var url ="https://10.11.13.155:9445/ibm/iis/igc-rest/v1/assets/6662c0f2.ee6a64fe.1mdlmv34b.anfhlbg.dmjrjk.5ct1qigk0ndbkd22sqp8i"+"?callback=JSON_CALLBACK";
$http({
   method: 'JSONP',
    url: url ,
     headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Basic xxxxx'}
})
.success(function (data) {
  console.log(data);`
  $scope.gridOptions.data = data.terms.items;
 });
```

Can someone help me what should I do here to capture the respnse coming from rest call.

Comment: What CORS issue did you run into? You glossed over it.

Comment: Simple Iam getting this error

XmlHttpRequest error: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: Have you tried setting the allowed origins?

Comment: I dont have access to set anything on server side

Comment: Is there anything that can be set on client side?

Comment: "Is there anything that can be set on client side?" — It would make the security restriction entirely useless if there was.

Comment: @Quentin ok ..then any solution in my case..I can see response coming in n/w tab.But unable to capturethat

Comment: The accepted answer on the duplicate question lists several alternatives to CORS … and explains why you can see the response in the network tab.